# WpAllImport retrieve a value from a xml row during import

Tags: xml, wpallimport

Im tryng to populate EAN field for every variation during post import so i need a functions that retrieve the value {upc_number[1]} and add on the variation field _amazon_id_

is there a way in php do retrieve this value from an xml ?

Comment: what i need is simply that php retrieve value from {upc_number[1]} xml node

Comment: Finally i added